# User not being update after logged in

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular11

I have an account service, which keeps track of the current user, after she logs in:

```
export class AccountService {     
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();
  ...

login(model: any) {      
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', model)
      .pipe(
        map((user: User) => {
          if (user) {
             localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
             this.currentUserSource.next(user);          
          }
        })
      );
  }
```

I also have a nav component that displays a drop down, only if the user exists:

TS:

```
constructor(public accountService: AccountService, private router: Router) {
..
```

Html:

```
 <div
    class="dropdown" 
    *ngIf="accountService.currentUser$ | async"
    dropdown
  >
```

The nav component works, **only** after a refresh. The user has to be log in, and then refresh the browser in order for the nav component to "know" she is logged in.
How do I fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

the reason for this problem is that you have not written codes in the primary component (app-component) to retrieve data from the localstorage , when pages are being refresh , app components needs data !

use these sample codes in in app-component :

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.setCurrentUser();
}


setCurrentUser() {
const user: User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
if (user) {
  this.accountService.setCurrentUser(user);
  this.presence.createHubConnection(user);
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32942792)

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you forgot in your nav component in **ngOnInit** check is isLogged

Create a new function in your service

```
isLogged()
{
    const user=localStorage.getItem('user');
    if (user)
       this.currentUserSource.next(JSON.parse(user))
    else
       this.currentUserSource.next(null)

    return user;
}
```

//and

```
ngOnInit()
{
     //you can only make a simple
     // this.accountService.isLogged() if you needn't
     // check if is logged

     if (this.accountService.isLogged())
          console.log("I'm logged")
     else
          console.log("I'm need log-in")
}
```

Comment: The nav component is initialized when the user open any page of the system, but he signs in through a specific component. So isLogged() is invoked once when the system loads, but never updates. I need to tell nav (that always exists) that the user signed in

Comment: your service is "provideIn:root"? when you make the "login(user).subscribe()" your "nav-component" is in the page -your page is like <app-nav></app-nav><router-outlet></router-outlet> and is in the router-outlet when you has the "login-component"? Has you forget subscribe to the service when login? (remember that you need **subscribe** to an observable if you want to be "executed")